# how to pull out every string between / and ; in tcl

Tags: tcl

I have `cat/bat/d;hen/jeep/e;ink/kin/l;` assigned to a variable

```
set f "cat/bat/d;hen/jeep/e;ink/kin/l;"
```

The output should be `d`; `e`; `l`

I tried using it with:

```
set ff [regexp -all -inline {/.*?;} $f]
```

but it gives

```
{/bat/d;} {/jeep/e;} {/kin/l;}
```

can you guys please suggest the solution using regexp?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use capture groups, and prevent any `;` or `/` in your matches. In code, that means:

```
set ff [regexp -all -inline -- {/([^;/]+);} $f]
```

This currently gives (the main match and their capture groups):

```
{/d;} d {/e;} e {/l;} l
```

You can use `lmap` to then take only the elements at even positions (the capture groups):

```
set ff [lmap {main capture} $ff {set capture}]
```

Which gives

```
d e l
```

Comment: Thank you. That was of great help